# Cannot download as project zip

Tags: divshot

Every time I chose "Export code" and click on download as project zip, nothing happens. tested with safari and chrome.

Is this feature not working yet or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

we've had reports of some issues in Firefox but it should be working in Chrome. Can you email support (at) divshot.com to give us some more details?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends if your project is huge or not but sometime (quite often actually). you will have to wait for sometime before the popup with saving settings appears Or it is that divshot server is really busy.